# How do you compare duplicate values?

Tags: c#

```
private int pic = 0;
private List<int> num = null;
.
.
.

.
.
public void ss(){   
this.imageList = new List<Image>();
this.imageList.Add(Properties.Resources.1);
this.imageList.Add(Properties.Resources.2);
this.imageList.Add(Properties.Resources.3);
.   
.   
.   
.
.
this.imageList.Add(Properties.Resources.58);
this.imageList.Add(Properties.Resources.59);
 this.pic = GetMyRandomNumber(0, 60); 

 if (this.num == null) 
    this.num= new List<int>(); 

 while (this.num.Count < 61) 
 { 
       pic = GetMyRandomNumber(0, 60); 

       if (this.num.Contains(pic) == false) 
       { 
             this.num.Add(pic); 
             break; 
       } 
 } 
 this.pictureBox1.Image = imageList[pic];
```

}

This code checks for duplicates when calling the ss method

Store the value in num, and check if the stored value is duplicated.

But the same value is stored in pic

duplicate values ​​continue to appear.

How do I fix it?

Comment: If you break the loop as soon as you add the first number to the list, how can the list contain even more than one item?  Let alone duplicates?  Please provide more debugging info.  Perhaps even a complete example we can check.

Comment: If you want a random ordering of the numbers 0 to 60 I suggest using the [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things could be happening here. Inside the "GetMyRandomNumber" method you may be using the "Random" class that needs to be used in a certain way to avoid the object retrieving the same value back to back and considerations for thread safety.

Here is a quote from MSDN on using "Random"

> Instead of instantiating individual Random objects, we recommend that you create a single Random instance to generate all the random numbers needed by your app. However, Random objects are not thread safe. If your app calls Random methods from multiple threads, you must use a synchronization object to ensure that only one thread can access the random number generator at a time. If you don't ensure that the Random object is accessed in a thread-safe way, calls to methods that return random numbers return 0.

It also appears you would like to keep track of the random numbers chosen.

Here is an alternate approach that will also help with the lookup speed.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HashSet<int> picked = new HashSet<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, 60));
        int pic = GetMyRandomNumber(picked);
        //...Other code here
    }

    private readonly static object _syncLock = new object();
    private readonly static Random _random = new Random();

    static int GetMyRandomNumber(HashSet<int> picked)
    {
        lock (_syncLock)
        {
            int rand = _random.Next(0, picked.Count);
            picked.Remove(rand);

            return rand;
        }
    }
```

This ensures that once you've chosen a random number from 0-60, it can't be chosen again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var nums = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5 };
        Print(nums);
        //REMOVE DUPLIDATED VALUES AT THE LINE BELOW
        nums = nums.Distinct().ToList();
        Print(nums);
        Console.Read();
    }

    public static void Print(List<int> nums)
    {
        foreach (var num in nums)
        {
            Console.Write(num.ToString() + ", ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.